# Probability of Second Feynman Point

Tags: probability, statistics, logic

What is the probability of the second sequence of six of the same digit in a row being of the same digit?

In pi, the first sequence of six of the same digits is composed of 9s. I see lots of posts about this, about how the probability of it occurring is very low by the point at which it occurs, digit 762-769 I guess. But it doesn't really shock me against the more bayesian question of how many other sequences in its place "could have occurred" (spread across every likely base) and gotten a similar level of reaction.  "Oh my God, the 69-73 digits of pi are 80085, clearly this is a sign from aliens or God, same diff really!!" Yah.

What does weird me out though is that the next sequence of six digits, the very next sequence, is also 9s. That just sits wrong with me for some reason. Call it paranoia and perhaps a smidge of insanity, lol. But there's so many random conspiracy theories floating around in the ether these days, from being in a simulation, to, yah, aliens and messages from god written in math...

Obviously it's just probability, just seems very weird. One weird sequence is easily dismissed, but having the very next sequence of the same class be identical makes the bayesian question into one that now revolves around how many classes of sequences are both notable and have notable, related early members, and that probability seems much smaller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi bot. I'm just wondering if it seems weird to anyone else, I guess. You're a computer, what do you think?

Comment: Why is Feynman's name cited? Don't you mean [Sagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan), whose 1985 novel [Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(novel)) brought up [the possibility of messages being placed in the digits of $\pi$ by super-advanced entities](https://web.archive.org/web/20021115003354/http://mathforum.org/discuss/sci.math/m/299360/299363) beyond our comprehension?